# custom name for root in route in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.5

I use these routes

```
Route::namespace('Panel\Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function (){
  $this->get('/', 'HomeController@index');

  $this->namespace('Users')->prefix('users')->group(function (){

    $this->get('/' , 'UserController@index')->name('users');
    $this->delete('/{user}/destroy' , 'UserController@destroy')->name('users.destroy');
    $this->get('/create' , 'UserController@create')->name('users.create');
    $this->post('/store' , 'UserController@store')->name('users.store');
    $this->get('/{user}/edit' , 'UserController@edit')->name('users.edit');
    $this->patch('/{user}/update' , 'UserController@update')->name('users.update');
```

it works.

for example with `php artisan route:list` I have these:

```
admin/users                               | users 
admin/users/create                        | users.create 
admin/users/store                         | users.store 
admin/users/{user}/destroy                | users.destroy
```

But I want write the code short:

```
Route::namespace('Panel\Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function (){
  $this->get('/', 'HomeController@index');

  $this->namespace('Users')->prefix('users')->group(function (){

    $this->resource('/' , 'UserController');
    $this->resource('/test' , 'UserController');
```

with `php artisan route:list` I have these:

```
admin/users                               | index 
admin/users                               | store 
admin/users/create                        | create 
admin/users/{}                            | show 
admin/users/{}                            | update 
admin/users/{}                            | destroy  
admin/users/{}/edit                       | edit
```

It's wrong. but for test is correct. for example:

```
admin/users/test                          | test.store 
admin/users/test/{test}/edit              | test.edit
```

what is my wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->resource('user' , 'UserController');
```

That will create all of your standard routes for users.

You should not include the prefix `user`, since it will create that.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `resource` method should be a name for the resource, 
so you should remove the `users` prefix and add `users` as name for the resource

```
$this->resource('users' , 'UserController');
```

you can read more about it on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)